# Adding subviews to an array of UIViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiview

I have a scroll view on which I have a main UIView. This main UIView has an array of UIViews in it.

I want to add a test view over this child view

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i<self.maxPage+1; i++) {
        CanvasBaseView *view =[[CanvasBaseView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (self.canvas.height.floatValue+NAPKIN_PADDING)*i, self.canvas.width.floatValue,self.canvas.height.floatValue)];
        [view addSubview:[self setDrawView:view]];
 }

-(UIView*)setDrawView:(UIView *)main{
    UIView *vw =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:main.frame];
    [vw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    return vw;
}
```

But when I do this only the first view has my new black background View. I tried it with Array of 2,6,10 and all of this only the first view is being populated

Even I tried this

```
UIView *vw = [UIView new];
vw.frame = main.frame;
[vw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
return vw;
```

Unfortunately same result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to add a black overlay to each child view in your loop. In that case you should use the bounds property of the parent view, as child views are relative it's parents view.

Change this line:

```
UIView *vw =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:main.frame];
```

To this:

```
UIView *vw =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:main.bounds];
```